# Independent events involving dice rolling and modulo

Tags: probability

We roll a dice with $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $p(\omega)=1/6$. Let $X,Y$ be random variables where X is the result of rolling the dice modulo 2 and Y is the result modulo 3. Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Now to show independence $P(X \cap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$ must hold. So far I have come to the conclusion that $X=\{0,1\},Y=\{0,1,2\}$ but how do I evaluate the probabilities? Clearly $X \cap Y=\{0,1\}$ but that's as far as I get.

Comment: What you need to show is that $P(X = j, Y = k) = P(X = j)P(Y = k)$ for $j = 0, 1$ and $k = 0, 1, 2$. $X$ and $Y$ are random variables—i.e., functions from a probability space into a measurable space—and what you've said $X$ and $Y$ are equal to are merely the ranges of those functions, not the functions themselves.

Comment: Your understanding of $X$ and $Y$ are incorrect.  $X$ and $Y$ here are random variables, not events.  Two *events* would be independent if the probability of their intersection was the product of their respective probabilities.  Here, these are two *random variables*, and random variables are independent if the respective events they correspond to are independent.  For instance the event $X=0$ corresponds to the event $\{2,4,6\}$ while the event $Y=1$ corresponds to the event $\{1,4\}$.  We ask if $(X=0)$ is independent of $(Y=1)$ and so on.

Comment: For the specific case of $(X=0)$ being independent of $(Y=1)$ we find $\Pr(X=0)=\Pr(\{2,4,6\})=\frac{3}{6}$ and $\Pr(Y=1)=\Pr(\{1,4\})=\frac{2}{6}$, that $\Pr(X=0,Y=1)=\Pr(\{4\})=\frac{1}{6}$ and that indeed $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$.  Repeat for the remaining possibilities, or better yet find a more convenient way to organize this to answer all at once.